# GLSL colour output is off by one as RGB

Tags: opengl, glsl

In GLSL, `outputColour = vec3(0, 0, 0.5)` outputs an RGB value of `(0, 0, 127)` instead of  `(0, 0, 128)`. Confirmed by `GL.ReadPixels()` and the Photoshop eyedropper tool.

Currently I'm bypassing the issue with `outputColour.b += 0.001` but I sure that will come back to haunt me later.

Has any body experienced this before and what is the solution?

Comment: It makes sense because the 8bit max value is 255. Try `128.0/255.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever OpenGL is asked to [convert a float to a normalized integer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Normalized_Integer#Unsigned), the implementation is allowed to do the rounding however it likes. So if it wants to chop off the decimal, that's fine.

If you need to control the rounding for normalization, then control it directly.

```
vec4 NormalizeColor(in vec4 input)
{
  vec4 denorm = input * 255.0;
  vec4 rounded = round(denorm);
  return rounded / 255.0;
}
```

You can replace the call to `round` with whatever you like.